# django-tinymce to work on all textareas in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, wysiwyg, django-tinymce

I have been trying to get tiny mce to work for my django admin site on all textareas without having to add each field's widget. I have a lot of forms and would like this to work as "automagically" as possible.

I have installed tiny mce using the "pip install django-tinymce" method.

I have followed the following article and even though it does not throw any errors in firebug or developer mode I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

https://blog.bixly.com/django-tinymce-in-djangos-admin-app

I have followed this to a the letter with no luck at all. Any thoughts or suggestions to get this working on all textareas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

jAC

Comment: Is it working for some text areas?

Comment: @AbijithMg no sir. I does not appear to work at all. No console errors though, so I believe it is loading fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by using admin.py's ModelAdmin classes.

For example:

```
@admin.register(HomePageSlider)
class HomePageSliderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ( '/static/assets/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js' , '/static/assets/js/tiny_mce/textareas.js' )
```

The first part is for the tinymce location and the second is loading the configuration that i threw in a textareas.js file.